# How to list hidden directory in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have created a directory and set a quota in HDFS using the following commands:

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/hdadmin/directorio_prueba
hdfs dfsadmin -setQuota 4 /user/hdadmin/directorio_prueba
```

The I have put some files in it:

```
hdfs dfs -put /opt/bd/ejemplo1.txt /user/hdadmin/directorio_prueba
hdfs dfs -put /opt/bd/ejemplo2.txt /user/hdadmin/directorio_prueba
hdfs dfs -put /opt/bd/ejemplo3.txt /user/hdadmin/directorio_prueba
```

But when I tried to put the fourth file, the HDFS did not let me saying "The NameSpace quota (directories and files) of directory /user/hdadmin/directorio_prueba is exceeded: quota=4 file count=5". I only have 3 files, but it says there are 4 items (directories and files in the directory). I have also used the following command to gather more information:

```
hdfs dfs -count -q -h -v /user/hdadmin/directorio_prueba
```

So there is a hidden directory there. What is this directory? Maybe "." or ".."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly view hidden files using the command

```
hdfs dfs -ls /user/hdfs
```

Please read [show hidden hdfs files](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Show-hidden-files-in-HDFS/td-p/203235)

Answer (score 0):

Reading the official documentation for the HDFS name quotas (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsQuotaAdminGuide.html) I found this: 'A quota of one forces a directory to remain empty. (Yes, a directory counts against its own quota!)'.

So there is not ".." nor "." directory. It is the directory itself that counts to the quota. However the "." directory is not explicitly shown. That is why the `hdfs dfs -ls /user/hdadmin/directorio_prueba` command did not show me any hidden directory like ".".